# Implementing numeric limit class

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and trying to implement a numeric limit class as :

```
internal class NumericLimit<TValue> where TValue : IComparable
{
    public NumericLimit(TValue min, TValue max)
    {
        this.Max = max;
        this.Min = min;
    }

    internal TValue Max { get; }
    internal TValue Min { get; }
    internal bool WithinBounds(TValue min, TValue max)
    {
        if (min.CompareTo(this.Min) <= 0 &&
            max.CompareTo(this.Max) >= 0)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    internal bool LessThan(TValue value)
    {
        return (value.CompareTo(this.Max) > 0);
    }

    internal bool GreaterThan(TValue value)
    {
        return (value.CompareTo(this.Min) < 0);
    }

    internal bool Contains(TValue value)
    {
        if (value.CompareTo(this.Max) == 0 ||
            value.CompareTo(this.Min) == 0)
            return true;

        return (value.CompareTo(this.Min) > 0) &&
               (value.CompareTo(this.Max) < 0);
    }

    internal bool Defined()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The problem is how to implement `Defined()` function. I want the `NumericLimit` to be invalid/undefined when both `Min` and `Max` values are -1.

Like, for `NumericLimit<long>` the limit is undefined when both Min and Max are -1L.

And for `NumericLimit<int>` the limit is undefined when both Min and Max are -1.

How to implement 'Defined' in a way that correctly represents `negative one` for `TValue` type ?

Comment: I would use `Nullable<TValue>` to store the limits, instead of relying on sentinel values to represent undefined values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if after some time you decide to use `NumericLimit<double>` or some other type for `T` that will not accept value of -1? I suggest using special `IsDefined` flag and adding static method for constructing undefined limit:

```
internal class NumericLimit<TValue> where TValue : IComparable
{
    internal bool IsDefined { get; }

    public NumericLimit(TValue min, TValue max)
    {
        this.Max = max;
        this.Min = min;
        IsDefined = true;
    }

    private NumericLimit()
    {
        IsDefined = false;
    }

    public static NumericLimit<TValue> Undefined()
    {
        return new NumericLimit<TValue>();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I like this technique of not relying on `negative one`